# Finding intervals of a contentious function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

The graph of the derivative f ' of a continuous function f is shown below. (Assume f ' continues to ∞.) [GRAPH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKkdQ.jpg)

(a) On what interval is f increasing? (Enter your answer in interval notation.)

On what interval is f decreasing? (Enter your answer in interval notation.)

(b) At what value(s) of x does f have a local maximum? (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)
x =

At what value(s) of x does f have a local minimum? (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)
x =

(c) On what interval is f concave upward? (Enter your answer in interval notation.)

On what interval is f concave downward? (Enter your answer in interval notation.)

(d) What are the x-coordinate(s) of the inflection point(s) of f ? (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)
x =

Comment: We cannot help you with a problem if you have not shown us what you have tried. If you could show us what you tried it would be easier to see where you went wrong.

Comment: a) (0,2),(4,6), (8,infinity)
, Decreasing (2,4) (6,8)
i got the first two wrong and gave up

Comment: That is correct, but what about your attempts for the other questions?

Comment: it says that those answers are wrong

Comment: what answers does it say?

Comment: It doesnt, however the graph is of f` and it is asking for f

Comment: i just do not know how to get that graph

Comment: You dont need the graph of the original function to explain its behaviour(especially minimia, maxima)

Comment: Okay. reentered the values and those were right. for the max and min would that be 2,4,8, where it crosses the axis?

Comment: You should determine whether the points are max or mins. While it's a necessary condition for the max points to have a derivative of 0, its not a sufficient condition. Consider $x = 2$. How do we know this is a max? Before the point, the function is increasing, suddenly after the point the function is decreasing, so at $x = 2$ a maximum occurs(the function kept "growing" until it got to some max point and began to decrease). Use this logic to decide whether a max or min occurs at 4 and 8

Comment: so 4, and 8 would be local minimums and 6 would be another local max

Comment: You cannot say 6 is a max because the function and its derivative is not defined at $x = 6$

Comment: Are there any other max's than x=2?

Comment: Where is this graph concave upward? (2,4),(6,8) was my answer